# ngIf else if in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would show message depending on a 2 values

```
<div *ngIf="nolimit; else limited">
   <p class="isGroup">No limit message</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="noDelegation; else limited">
   <p class="isGroup">No delegation</p>
</div>
<ng-template #limited>
  Content here
</ng-template>
```

I would that either `isGroup` message shows or `no delegation` if they are both false I should show content `#limited`

My actual problem is that I get no limit message and `#limited` content together when `nolimit` is true:

> no limit
>
> Content Here

But When I delete `no delegation` code, evetything is working.

Comment: Why not creating three divs and then using `*ngIf="!nolimit && !noDelegation"` on the last one that will show `Content here` text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use three `div`s and then use `*ngIf="!nolimit && !noDelegation"` on the last one that will show `Content here` text

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="nolimit">
    <p class="isGroup">No limit message</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="noDelegation">
    <p class="isGroup">No delegation</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!nolimit && !noDelegation">
  Content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the microsintax:

```
<div [ngIf]="nolimit" [ngIfElse]="limited">
  <p class="isGroup">No limit message</p>
</div>

<div [ngIf]="noDelegation" [ngIfElse]="limited">
  <p class="isGroup">No delegation</p>
</div>

<ng-template #limited>
 Content here
</ng-template>
```